# Mute Emergency alert in Google Now (without removing it)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now, alerts

Google Now has a neat feature (at least I think it's from Google Now) where it warns you for emergency events. The problem is it's just warned me twice in half an hour with an extremely loud tone about a snowstorm I've known about for days.

Is there some way I can make the phone vibrate or change the ringtone? I only see an option to disable these alerts entirely. It's not my default notification/alarm ringtone; it's a special LOUD warning tone. Good at attracting attention but major overkill. I would like to still get them, but I would like them to be much quieter (yes, even though they're "emergencies") as my phone blaring loud warning tones at work is quite distracting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have a working phone on hand at the moment to test this, but if you can identify the specific audio file used as the alert sound, you could simply edit it with a piece of software like Audacity and make it as quiet as you'd like. (Excuse the shoddy answer, I'll edit it as soon as I can test the method or delete it straight away if it's unsatisfactory)

Comment: There's an idea...do you know what the audio for that happens to be? It's not something I can set

Answer (score 2):

If you go to google now, and then go to settings (the three dot menu button if its a soft key) theres a section that says notifications. That section has a part titled Urgent Updates and has the option to set a ringtone or turn on vibrate. As far as I know this should change the sound for the alert since it says urgent updates include public alerts. Just note, I am using KitKat so if you don't have the latest version of google now it could be different. 
EDIT: I just realized this question was asked a year ago so the answer details a newer version

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the exact same issue (same storm too, no doubt). In Android 4.2, you can disable these alerts by going to *Settings → Wireless Networks (More...) → Cell broadcasts*. The alerts cannot be muted, but can be disabled in this screen.

Comment: The questioner asked about how to mute the Google Now alerts and not alerts received via cell broadcasts.

Answer (score -2):

On my phone, which runs Android Gingerbread, this setting is under Sound\Emergency\Emergency Tone. I have set it to OFF, as opposed to Alert or Vibrate.

Comment: And which phone (running which Android version) is it?

Comment: @wbogacz if your phone is running Gingerbread (Android 2.3), then you don't have [Google Now](http://www.google.co.uk/landing/now/), as it's only compatible with Android 4.1 (Jellybean) and newer.